# Regex for selecting entire sections based on text in section

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text with multiple repeating sections with different values:

```
Section
-------
Property1: Val-a
Property2: 

 <dict>
 <key>key</key>
 <data>my data</data> 
 </dict>

Property3: Val-123

Section
-------
Property1: Val-c
Property2: Val-d
Property3: Val-4

Section
-------
Property1: Val-e
Property2: Val-f
Property3: Val-f

Section
-------
Property1: Val-gg
Property2: Val-d
Property3: Val-h

Section
-------
Property1: Val-x 
Property2: Val-f
Property3: Val-9
```

I'd like to get all sections that have Property2: Val-d. I would like to get the entire section with all properties and values. In the above example I would like to end up with the second and fourth section:

```
Section
-------
Property1: Val-c
Property2: Val-d
Property3: Val-4
```

and

```
Section
-------
Property1: Val-gg
Property2: Val-d
Property3: Val-h
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is regex a must? Cuz `result = [i for i in test.split("\n\n") if "Val-d" in i]` is much easier to get the result you want.

Comment: There may be ("\n\n") within the section as well. I've updated the example

Comment: Since there are already regex answers, heres another non-regex method: `result = [f"{'' if num ==0 else 'S'}{i}" for num,i in enumerate(test.split("\nS")) if "Val-d" in i]`

Comment: What is it with the `<dict>...</dict>` stuff in there? Maybe just present real-life data.

Answer (score 1):

Could be further optimized:

```
^Section
(?:(?!^Section)[\s\S])+?
^Property2:\ Val-d
(?:(?!^Section)[\s\S])+?
(?=^Section|\Z)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XMKWcc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode:

```
(?m)^Section(?:\n[^\n]+)+?\nProperty2: Val-d(?:\n[^\n]+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T859Xf/2)